# ec2 free tier, I run :yum update, which will generate fee?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I build a ec2 instance(RHEL), and run : yum update, and system tip: there is 300M need update. And I check yes and system update many libs. My question is: will this 300M generate fee?

Answer (score 1):

No, it wont. <s>The free tier includes 1GB free regional data transfer.</s>

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Updating the system could cause regional data transfer – your instance is in one Availability Zone and the update server in another. As long as your updates stay below 1GB, you should be safe.

**Update**

The regional data transfer does not matter. As stated by slayedbylucifer in his answer, all incoming data transfer is free as of July 1, 2011.

Answer (score 1):

All Incoming data traffic is free. please refer: http://aws.amazon.com/pricing_effective_july_2011/

So, in your case, when you do `yum update`, it doesn't really matter how big the update is going to be. It will not be charged as its all incoming data.

Also please read this carefully: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/#DataTransfer

You should not incur any charges for running `yum update`.

Comment: I was reading an outdated source. Ty for clarifications (+1).